# Hyperledger fabric2.0 peer lifecycle chaincode approveformyorg Error: timed out waiting for txid on all peers

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-chaincode

The config looks good, and I can successfully run package and install. However, `approveformyorg` return this error: `timed out waiting for txid on all peers`.

I don't know how to debug this error. I have tried to change some environment variables (like `CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE`, `CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH`).

Is it a network error? Or is the order set wrong?

Thanks for your help!

[Running picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZqCJ.png)

Comment: Have you found the solution ?. I am also facing the same issue. I checked the connection between the orderer and peer it is working but still I am facing this issue.

Comment: I had this problem and it was because I was taking apart the sample script file and incorrectly left one of the parameters as "NA", so the chaincode call included a few ` NA NA`. After removing those it worked fine.

Comment: Has anyone found a working solution?

Answer (score 2):

I have encountered the same problem。The reason for my problem is that the DNS Server in Docker cannot resolve the domain name of the orderer node。It does not use the DNS settings in /etc/hosts。So the peer node can not connect to the ordering service to receive the blockWhen you check the log of the peer node, you will find that there is no such host.
Therefore, I added extra_hosts to the docker-compose.yaml files of all nodes(include orderer nodes).The document is https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/ .Next I deleted and rebuilt all services。Now it has worked.

Comment: I added the hostAlias in Kubernetes but still having the same error

Answer (score 1):

you need to add the orderer ip address to the etc/hosts file in the format mentioned below

orderer.example.com

P.S.  I also faced the same issue and it got resolved

Answer (score 0):

This happend to me when my order and my peer wasn't able to interract with each other.
Take a look at your peer and orderer logs to check if their is no network error.