# Hyperledger Fabric 2.4 approve chaincode error

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I'm setting up an hyperledger fabric network with docker compose.
All the containers are up and running but i'm having problems with the appprovemyorg command.
These are the logs of the peer after joining the channel:

```
    2022-05-24 07:41:54.316 UTC 0023 INFO [ledgermgmt] CreateLedger -> Creating ledger [mychannel] with genesis block
    2022-05-24 07:41:54.319 UTC 0024 INFO [blkstorage] newBlockfileMgr -> Getting block information from block storage
    2022-05-24 07:41:54.328 UTC 0025 INFO [kvledger] commit -> [mychannel] Committed block [0] with 1 transaction(s) in 6ms (state_validation=0ms block_and_pvtdata_commit=3ms state_commit=1ms) commitHash=[]
    2022-05-24 07:41:54.328 UTC 0026 INFO [kvledger] updateLedgerStatus -> Updating ledger [mychannel] status to [ACTIVE]
    2022-05-24 07:41:54.329 UTC 0027 INFO [ledgermgmt] CreateLedger -> Created ledger [mychannel] with genesis block
    2022-05-24 07:41:54.332 UTC 0028 INFO [gossip.gossip] JoinChan -> Joining gossip network of channel mychannel with 1 organizations
    2022-05-24 07:41:54.332 UTC 0029 INFO [gossip.gossip] learnAnchorPeers -> No configured anchor peers of org1MSP for channel mychannel to learn about
    2022-05-24 07:41:54.333 UTC 002a INFO [gateway] configUpdate -> Updating orderer config channel=mychannel
    2022-05-24 07:41:54.333 UTC 002b INFO [gossip.state] NewGossipStateProvider -> Updating metadata information for channel mychannel, current ledger sequence is at = 0, next expected block is = 1
    2022-05-24 07:41:54.333 UTC 002c INFO [endorser] callChaincode -> finished chaincode: cscc duration: 21ms channel= txID=a704dc84
    2022-05-24 07:41:54.333 UTC 002d INFO [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> unary call completed grpc.service=protos.Endorser grpc.method=ProcessProposal grpc.peer_address=172.22.0.9:59204 grpc.code=OK grpc.call_duration=22.209824ms
    2022-05-24 07:42:00.335 UTC 002e INFO [gossip.election] beLeader -> 49ad88f230e73d14bb6f9b8a891c0f5bc47a35cd793ff62222e489f762864a33 : Becoming a leader
    2022-05-24 07:42:00.335 UTC 002f INFO [gossip.service] func1 -> Elected as a leader, starting delivery service for channel mychannel
    2022-05-24 07:42:00.335 UTC 0030 INFO [deliveryClient] StartDeliverForChannel -> This peer will retrieve blocks from ordering service and disseminate to other peers in the organization for channel mychannel
2022-05-24 07:30:08.206 UTC 0031 WARN [peer.blocksprovider] DeliverBlocks -&gt; Could not connect to ordering service: could not dial endpoint &apos;orderer2:8050&apos;: failed to create new connection: connection error: desc = &quot;transport: error while dialing: dial tcp 0.0.0.0:8050: connect: connection refused&quot; channel=mychannel
    2022-05-24 07:30:08.307 UTC 0032 WARN [peer.blocksprovider] DeliverBlocks -&gt; Could not connect to ordering service: could not dial endpoint &apos;orderer3:9050&apos;: failed to create new connection: connection error: desc = &quot;transport: error while dialing: dial tcp 0.0.0.0:9050: connect: connection refused&quot; channel=mychannel
    2022-05-24 07:30:08.428 UTC 0033 WARN [peer.blocksprovider] DeliverBlocks -&gt; Could not connect to ordering service: could not dial endpoint &apos;orderer1:7050&apos;: failed to create new connection: connection error: desc = &quot;transport: error while dialing: dial tcp 0.0.0.0:7050: connect: connection refused&quot; channel=mychannel
```

As you can see, i have some warnings but I can safely join the channel and I have no problems at all when i install the chaincode (the warnings disappear too).
These are the logs on the peer after installing the chaincode:

```
2022-05-24 07:45:17.017 UTC 0052 INFO [chaincode.externalbuilder.ccaas_builder] waitForExit -> ::Detect command=detect
2022-05-24 07:45:17.017 UTC 0053 INFO [chaincode.externalbuilder.ccaas_builder] waitForExit -> ::Error: chaincode type not supported: java command=detect
2022-05-24 07:45:17.023 UTC 0054 INFO [lifecycle] InstallChaincode -> Successfully installed chaincode with package ID 'testchaincode_1:de8cddcb2deda13a7a3c1e9f6e37764e6d2c1bb6f89bac1f0d2c6396587b35f7'
2022-05-24 07:45:17.023 UTC 0055 INFO [endorser] callChaincode -> finished chaincode: _lifecycle duration: 14ms channel= txID=694acf7b
2022-05-24 07:45:17.023 UTC 0056 INFO [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> unary call completed grpc.service=protos.Endorser grpc.method=ProcessProposal grpc.peer_address=172.22.0.9:59206 grpc.code=OK grpc.call_duration=15.8101ms
```

When i try to approve the chaincode with this command:

```
peer lifecycle chaincode approveformyorg --tls --cafile /tmp/hyperledger/org1/peer1/tls-msp/tlscacerts/tls-tls-ca-7052.pem -o orderer1:7050 --ordererTLSHostnameOverride orderer1 --channelID mychannel --name mycc --version 1 --sequence 1 --waitForEvent --init-required --package-id testchaincode_1:de8cddcb2deda13a7a3c1e9f6e37764e6d2c1bb6f89bac1f0d2c6396587b35f7
```

I have this error:

```
Error: timed out waiting for txid on all peers
```

With these logs on the peer:

```
    2022-05-24 07:46:54.303 UTC 0059 INFO [lifecycle] ApproveChaincodeDefinitionForOrg -> Successfully endorsed chaincode approval with name 'mycc', package ID 'testchaincode_1:de8cddcb2deda13a7a3c1e9f6e37764e6d2c1bb6f89bac1f0d2c6396587b35f7', on channel 'mychannel' with definition {sequence: 1, endorsement info: (version: '1', plugin: 'escc', init required: true), validation info: (plugin: 'vscc', policy: '12202f4368616e6e656c2f4170706c69636174696f6e2f456e646f7273656d656e74'), collections: ()}
    2022-05-24 07:46:54.303 UTC 005a INFO [endorser] callChaincode -> finished chaincode: _lifecycle duration: 0ms channel=mychannel txID=d56b21b6
    2022-05-24 07:46:54.308 UTC 005b INFO [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> unary call completed grpc.service=protos.Endorser grpc.method=ProcessProposal grpc.peer_address=172.22.0.9:59210 grpc.code=OK grpc.call_duration=6.78249ms
    2022-05-24 07:46:55.194 UTC 005c WARN [peer.blocksprovider] DeliverBlocks -> Could not connect to ordering service: could not dial endpoint 'orderer1:7050': failed to create new connection: connection error: desc = "transport: error while dialing: dial tcp 0.0.0.0:7050: connect: connection refused" channel=mychannel
    2022-05-24 07:47:24.311 UTC 005d INFO [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> streaming call completed grpc.service=protos.Deliver grpc.method=DeliverFiltered grpc.request_deadline=2022-05-24T07:47:24.31Z grpc.peer_address=172.22.0.9:59212 error="context finished before block retrieved: context deadline exceeded" grpc.code=Unknown grpc.call_duration=30.0006887s
2022-05-24 07:47:54.260 UTC 005e WARN [peer.blocksprovider] DeliverBlocks -> Could not connect to ordering service: could not dial endpoint 'orderer2:8050': failed to create new connection: connection error: desc = "transport: error while dialing: dial tcp 0.0.0.0:8050: connect: connection refused" channel=mychannel
```

So i can't approve the chaincode and advance in the process.
Can anyone help me solve this problem?
Thanks

Comment: Can you provide a bit more information about how you have set up your Fabric network? It looks like this might be the same problem as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60834212/hyperledger-fabric2-0-peer-lifecycle-chaincode-approveformyorg-error-timed-out

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I already solved the issue. This was a DNS configuration problem