# Error: timed out waiting for txid on all peers while executing approveformyorg in chaincode lifecycle - HLF2.3

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zefxr.png)

Tried the answers given in the below link but not working

[Hyperledger fabric2.0 peer lifecycle chaincode approveformyorg Error: timed out waiting for txid on all peers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60834212/hyperledger-fabric2-0-peer-lifecycle-chaincode-approveformyorg-error-timed-out)

It will be helpful is anyone found the solution for this error.. Thanks in advance !!!!!

Answer (score 0):

In my experience with Fabric, those kind of errors are often due to either a bad configuration (e.g. bad certificates, peer not actually running, etc.) or a network issue (e.g. your host machine is not able to resolve the peer's hostname into the related IP address, etc.).

You can try to issue a simpler command, such as [`peer lifecycle chaincode queryinstalled`](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/commands/peerlifecycle.html#peer-lifecycle-chaincode-queryinstalled), and see what happens. If it works, you can exclude network issues.

Good luck!